# WordPress Blog Pagination Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, blogs

I'm still stuck on this issue..

The pagination on my WordPress blog is not working - http://www.example.com/news

When you click a different page number it updates the URL (and page title) correctly but it does not show different posts.

Ive tried:

- Disabling all plug-ins
- Changing the permalink structure
- Changing the number of blog posts displayed in Settings>Reading
- Changing http://www.example.com/recall-news to a different path to avoid conflicting with a post category named "news"

Nothing has worked for me.

I've seen many solutions for a custom query, but I'm using the posts page that you set in Settings>Reading>Posts Page so I did not write any code to display the posts on this page.

- What WordPress file do I modify to fix the blog pagination in this case? I'm guessing I can add something to functions.php, but I haven't found a solution yet.

UPDATE: I have not found the solution yet. I know I can do it by writing my own query but I want to stick with the default WP blog.

Comment: On which template/page is this exactly. Also, post your template code.

Comment: You definitely don't need a custom query.  BUT, we need you to provide the code from your theme template that renders the `recall-news` page.  Without it, there is NO WAY for us to troubleshoot or help.

Answer (score 3):

Check your WP loop in the category.php file (aka archive.php).  It must contain the following:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

and finished with:

```
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Sorry? Can you expand on that for me?

Answer (score 2):

I have played with the "posts pages" too but I'm getting no result.

Only working solution for me was a custome query in combination with the [Page-Navi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) Plugin.

In my template i have the following code:

```
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 5,
        'paged'             => $paged,
    );
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $displaylist = '<div class="list-group">';

        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();

            // build up your entry

            unset( $displayTag );
        }

        $displaylist .= '</div>';

        echo( $displaylist );

        wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $q ) );

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```

With the `post_per_page` i manage the entries per site. In while loop i build up the entries that should be showed.

Comment: This works in my end, you can also use this for the search page when navigating to a paginated search result

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that your issue is WordPress related. However, because you haven't given a very general question, I am going to give you a very general answer. This should aid you in figuring out what is wrong and solving it yourself.

1. Check out [underscores](http://underscores.me/). Download it and review the templates (like `index.php`, `archive.php`, etc.) to see if you're missing something that underscores includes. The nice thing about underscores is that it's all the basic stuff you need to create a running theme, with no frills. So, if it's there and not in your code, it may be worth exploring. Take special care for any code blocks relating to `have_posts`.
2. **It may not actually be anything wrong with your theme.** Try testing another theme (say, underscores, which you've conveniently downloaded) to see if it has pagination working and intact. If it does, then, you're in luck... That means you just have to dig a bit deeper to reconcile what's wrong with your code that's right with underscores.
3. If you've discovered that it's not something wrong with your theme but in fact something wrong with your server configuration, that's also something of a relief, in a matter of speaking. It means that you should theoretically be able to test your installation somewhere else, or reinstall your server, and make it work. Before going that far, try to simply reinstall your version of WordPress. Who knows... It could work.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the "page"/"paged" var in the query_post function:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
 $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
 $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
 $paged = 1;
}
query_posts(array('paged' => $paged));
if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!--Your HTML-->.
<?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [Wp-Pagenavi](https://hr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for generating your pagination? That way we can at least check if the problem is the default pagination or just some error in the coding that is not filling the paged variable correctly

Comment: why a plugin for a default pagination ?

the_posts_pagination() or get_the_posts_pagination() are already aviable from core also paginate_links().

Comment: More plugins > increase page load and db fetch ... So max use wp core methods if possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    global $wpdb;

    $pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
    $limit = 20;
    $offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
    //$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}design_information LIMIT $offset, $limit" );
     $entries = $wpdb->get_results("Select * From design_information ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit",ARRAY_A);

echo '<div class="wrap">';
<table class="widefat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>SNo.</th><th>Layout</th><th>Org Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php if( $entries ) { ?>

            <?php
            $count = 1;
            $class = '';
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($entries);
    for($i=0;$i<count($entries); $i++)
    {

$pid=$entries[$i]['id'];
                $class = ( $count % 2 == 0 ) ? ' class="alternate"' : '';
          ?>
            <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                <td>
              <?php echo $entries[$i]['id'];
                //echo $count; 
                $count++;?>
          </td>
<td>
      <?php echo $entries[$i]['layout'];?>
  </td>
  <td> 
      <?php echo $entries[$i]['org_description'];?>
  </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file archive-learning.php in your theme.

That mean post_type is "learning"

```html
<?php
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    } 


<?php
$custom_args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'learning',
        'post_status'   => 'public',
        'orderby'       =>  'date',
        'order'         =>'DESC',    
         'posts_per_page'=>12,//limit 6
         'paged' => $paged
    );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
$getPosts =  get_posts($custom_args);

?>
<?php if ($getPosts) : ?>
    <?php global $post,$wp_query;?>
    <?php foreach ($getPosts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post);?>
    <?php echo "your content here";?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
     
    <?php
    else :
     
     

    endif;
   ?>
<div class="pagenation"><?php if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {custom_pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);} ?></div></div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

go to file functions.php and create function custom_pagination

```html
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  /*
   * This first part of our function is a fallback
   * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
   * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
   * 
   * It's good because we can now override default pagination
   * in our theme, and use this function in default queries
   * and custom queries.
   */
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }

  /** 
   * We construct the pagination arguments to enter into our paginate_links
   * function. 
   */
  
  $pagination_args = array(
  'base'           =>add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
  'format'          => 'page/%#%',
  'total'           => $numpages,
  'current'         => $paged,
  'show_all'        => False,
  'end_size'        => 1,
  'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
  'prev_next'       => True,
  'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
  'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
  'type'            => 'plain',
  'add_args'        => false,
  'add_fragment'    => ''
);

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
      //echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
      echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you use the custom permalink structure /%category%/%postname%/ which was indeed my case.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvQ6dQf2DKo) and [its text version](https://www.theblogmechanic.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-pagination-not-working/) fixed it for me like a charm.

In short, installing this plugin solved my problem:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-category-prev-next-link-fix/#description