# Wordpress pagination not working/displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am trying to get wordpress pagination to display at the bottom of the page but nothing shows up, if I echo out "paged" it outputs 1 so I believe it is correctly reading the page it is on. The loop I am using is as follows:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'company_list', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

To echo out the actual pagination at the bottom of the page I am using:

```
echo paginate_links( $loop );
```

Currently no pagination is being displayed at the bottom of the page but the loop is working correctly. The page is also not set as a static front page.

Thanks.

Comment: how many posts are there in your record ? try changing posts_per_page => 6 to lower values..say 2 or 3 and check if pagination is visible

Comment: @DrMJ Currently 7 posts exist within that post type, I tried limiting to three earlier but it still only displayed the three and no pagination.

Answer (score 0):

1)You do not have to use question mark in your first row

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?
```

2)also see :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757648/10210277